# WebEx: is there way to remote control privileged programs when UAC is enabled?

Tags: uac, webex

So I'm hosting a WebEx meeting with someone, and he's sharing his screen with me.
He's using Windows system and UAC is turned on(as by default).
Whenever a privileged program (one that's run as administrator) is activated, I lose control over his screen.  Seems that I can only control normal applications, but not privileged programs.

This is kind of stupid to me, as in my opinion a great deal of WebEx sessions are to do administrative stuff.

Disabling UAC is an option. but are there other ways?

I've tried running IE as administrator, then use that window to open the WebEx link, which didn't work either.

Comment: You will have to use a different solution that handles UAC prompts correctly.